# CasperJS 1.1.0-beta2 test example resulting in UncaughtError

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, phantomjs, casperjs

I would love to use CasperJS to run tests against the PhantomJS headless browser. There is great documentation, but this example I would like to follow does not work. Has anyone been able to get this to work, or can someone find a problem with my implementation? I am referencing this "[Advanced Technique](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/testing.html#advanced-techniques)" in the CasperJS Documentation:

```
//cow-test-ref.js
function Cow() {
    this.mowed = false;
    this.moo = function moo() {
        this.mowed = true; // mootable state: don't do that at home
        return 'moo!';
    };
}
casper.test.begin('Cow can moo', 2, {
    setUp: function(test) {
        this.cow = new Cow();
    },
    tearDown: function(test) {
        this.cow.destroy();
    },
    test: function(test) {
        test.assertEquals(this.cow.moo(), 'moo!');
        test.assert(this.cow.mowed);
        test.done();
    }
});
```

My Result is the following error:

```
m@mPro marketing_qa $ casperjs --version
1.1.0-beta2
m@mPro tests $ casperjs test cow-test-ref.js
Test file: cow-test-ref.js
# Cow can moo
PASS Subject equals the expected value
PASS Subject is strictly true
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.cow.destroy()')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    file: cow-test-ref.js:14
#    error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.cow.destroy()')
#           TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.cow.destroy()')
#               at cow-test-ref.js:14
#               at done (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta2/libexec/modules/tester.js:1067)
#               at cow-test-ref.js:20
#               at /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta2/libexec/modules/tester.js:986
#               at /usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta2/libexec/bin/bootstrap.js:51
#               at begin (/usr/local/Cellar/casperjs/1.1-beta2/libexec/modules/tester.js:1015)
#               at cow-test-ref.js:21
#    stack: not provided
FAIL 3 tests executed in 0.023s, 2 passed, 1 failed, 0 dubious, 0 skipped.
```

Has anyone encountered this, or worked around this successfully? I'd love to use this test pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The `destroy` method is used as an example to highlight the concept of the principle behind `tearDown`. The method is not implemented in the original code, so the error you get is normal.